# Как правильно парсить XSLT-файл?

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, xslt

Добрый день!

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно парсить XSLT-файл ?**
Я хочу вытянуть имена колонок ("Имя:", "город:".. и т.д.)
Я сейчас так делаю:

> XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();         
> XMLDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
> + String.Format(@"Templates\Abonent_{0}.xslt",
> client_type));

т.е. через XML. парсится, но криво.

Сам файл:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

```
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <table cellSpacing="3" cellPadding="2" border="0" width="100%">
      <xsl:if test="AbonentRepresentation/AbonentType='Person'">
          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName" width="15%">Имя:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue" width="35%">
                  <input id="Name" DynamicName="Name" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Name" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName" width="15%">Город:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue" width="35%">
                  <input id="City" DynamicName="City" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic"  style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/City" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">ЕРДПОУ:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <input id="ERDPOU" DynamicName="ERDPOU" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/ERDPOU" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName">Физ. адрес:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <textarea id="PAddress" DynamicName="PAddress" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" rows="2" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/PAddress" />
                  </textarea>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">Факс:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <input id="Fax" DynamicName="Fax" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Fax" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName">E-mail:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <input id="Email" DynamicName="Email" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Email" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">Телефон:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <textarea id="Phone" DynamicName="Phone" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" rows="2" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Phone" />
                  </textarea>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName">Договор:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <textarea id="Contract" DynamicName="Contract" type="text" cntrType="txta" class="Dynamic" rows="2" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Contract" />
                  </textarea>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">Пол:</td>
              <td>
                  <table>
                      <tr>
                          <td nowrap="True" class="DynamicValue">
                              <input id="Radio1" type="radio" DynamicName="Sex" name="G1" onclick="SelectDynamicRadio('Sex', 'm');">
                                  <xsl:if test="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Sex='m'">
                                      <xsl:attribute name="checked">
                                          checked
                                      </xsl:attribute>
                                  </xsl:if>
                              </input>мужской
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td nowrap="True" class="DynamicValue">
                              <input id="Radio0" type="radio" DynamicName="Sex" name="G1" onclick="SelectDynamicRadio('Sex', 'f');">
                                  <xsl:if test="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Sex='f'">
                                      <xsl:attribute name="checked">
                                          checked
                                      </xsl:attribute>
                                  </xsl:if>
                              </input>женский
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <td>
                      <input id="Sex" DynamicName="Sex" class="Dynamic" cntrType="radio" type="hidden" >
                          <xsl:attribute name="value">
                              <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Sex" />
                          </xsl:attribute>
                      </input>
                  </td>
              </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">Примечания:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue" colSpan="3">
                  <textarea id="Remark" DynamicName="Remark" type="text" cntrType="txta" class="Dynamic" rows="5" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Remark" />
                  </textarea>
              </td>
          </tr>

      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="AbonentRepresentation/AbonentType='Organization'">
      <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName" width="15%">Название(полное):</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue" width="35%">
                  <input id="Name" DynamicName="Name" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Name" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName" width="15%">Город:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue" width="35%">
                  <input id="City" DynamicName="City" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic"  style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/City" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">ЕРДПОУ:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <input id="ERDPOU" DynamicName="ERDPOU" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/ERDPOU" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName">ОКПО:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <input id="IndTaxNumb" DynamicName="IndTaxNumb" cntrType="tbx" type="text" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/IndTaxNumb" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>          
              <td class="DynamicName">Факс:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <input id="Fax" DynamicName="Fax" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Fax" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName">E-mail:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <input id="Email" DynamicName="Email" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Email" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">Юр. адрес:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <input id="JAddress" DynamicName="JAddress" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" style="width:90%;">
                      <xsl:attribute name="value">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/JAddress" />
                      </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">Физ. адрес:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <textarea id="PAddress" DynamicName="PAddress" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" rows="2" style="width:90%;">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/PAddress" />
                  </textarea>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName">Телефон:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <textarea id="Phone" DynamicName="Phone" type="text" cntrType="tbx" class="Dynamic" rows="2" style="width:90%;">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Phone" />
                  </textarea>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td class="DynamicName">Контактные лица:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <textarea id="Contact" DynamicName="Contact" type="text" cntrType="txta" class="Dynamic" rows="2" style="width:90%;">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Contact" />
                  </textarea>
              </td>
              <td class="DynamicName">Договор:</td>
              <td class="DynamicValue">
                  <textarea id="Contract" DynamicName="Contract" type="text" cntrType="txta" class="Dynamic" rows="2" style="width:90%;">
                          <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Contract" />
                  </textarea>
              </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="DynamicName">Примечания:</td>
            <td class="DynamicValue" colSpan="3">
                <textarea id="Remark" DynamicName="Remark" type="text" cntrType="txta" class="Dynamic" rows="5" style="width:90%;">
                    <xsl:value-of select="AbonentRepresentation/Data/Remark" />
                </textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </xsl:if>

    </table>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Спасибо!**

Comment: XSLT - это больше как шаблонизатор нежели как формат хранения данных.
Парсить можно как обычный XML файл - использовать можно тот же SimpleXML + XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сработал XML + XPath.